# How to scale a DIV to 100% of browser size?

Tags: html, css

I've a webforms ASP.NET application with a master page and a child page.

Inside child page i've some div like:

```
<html>

<div>
  ....
  <div id="MYDIV">
    <textarea> .... </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add a function to make my div containing textarea full browser size .

I've tried adding an image with an onClick function:

```
<img src="images/full-screen.png" height="16px" onclick="document.getElementById('divEditorReferto').style.height = '100vh'; document.getElementById('divEditorReferto').style.width = '100vh';" />
```

But it not works.

Second question: how to reverse the full screen function and make div with the old parameters (normal size) ?

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Your title says you want a 100% browser size div. Then you want a full screen textbox and then you say something about a 100vh image.

Comment: `position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Add a on click event that toggles a class .e.g. `class="example"`. Then style elements accordingly.

```
#MYDIV.example {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple vanilljs to toggle class

```
var el = document.querySelector('.toggleFull');
var content = document.querySelector('.textAreaWrapper');
el.onclick = function() {
  content.classList.toggle('full');
}
```

css with the normal and the fullscreen version of the textarea and the positioning of the toggle button (.toggleFull)

```
.textAreaWrapper {
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
  position:relative;
}

.textAreaWrapper.full {
  position:absolute;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:flex;
}

.textAreaWrapper .textAreaInner {
  flex-grow:1;
}

.textAreaWrapper.full .textAreaInner {
  height:100vh!important;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.toggleFull{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Here a working fiddle:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pMEXLR?editors=1111